# User.findOne() Always throw error Cannot read property '_id' of undefined - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

Here is my Middleware with **Passport**

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
usernameField: 'email',
passwordField: 'password',
passReqToCallback: true
}, function (req, email, password, done) {
User.findOne({ email: email}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return done(err);

    if(!user) {
        return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user    found!'));
    }

    if (!user.comparePassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.'));
    }

    return done(null, user);
});
}));
```

and this is my login POST method

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}));
```

After that, I'm trying to redirect to GET Profile page like that:

```
router.get('/profile', function (req, res, next) {
    User.findOne({'user._id': req.user._id}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        res.render('accounts/profile', { user : user});
    });
});
```

Signup method woking correctly and send data to Database, but it's also has the error to redirecting to Profile page with the same TypeError !

Finally , here is dependencies in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
"body-parser": "^1.15.2",
"connect-mongo": "^1.3.2",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
"ejs": "^2.5.5",
"ejs-mate": "^2.3.0",
"express": "^4.14.0",
"express-flash": "0.0.2",
"express-session": "^1.14.2",
"mongoose": "^4.7.4",
"morgan": "^1.7.0",
"passport": "^0.3.2",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0"
}
```

I hope someone helps me, I'm stuck here! I can't move on.

Comment: `req.user` seems to be undefined.

Comment: I think user is not serialized to session.

Comment: @str  I defined it like so  `app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    next();
});`

Comment: @user29 I'm using both functions `passport.serializeUser` and `passport.deserializeUser` !

Comment: @AhmedSalahBasha That does not define `req.user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my error by just Downgrade some dependencies in my *package.json* file 
dependencies will be like so:

```
  "dependencies": {
"bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
"body-parser": "^1.14.2",
"connect-mongo": "^1.1.0",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.0",
"ejs": "^2.3.4",
"ejs-mate": "^2.3.0",
"express": "^4.13.3",
"express-flash": "0.0.2",
"express-session": "^1.12.1",
"mongoose": "^4.3.4",
"morgan": "^1.6.1",
"passport": "^0.3.2",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0"
}
```

Then everything going correctly, at least in my case :) 
Thanks All.

Answer (score 1):

here you are trying to access user_id directly from the req object.

```
User.findOne({'user._id': req.user._id},
```

change it to

```
router.post('/profile', function (req, res, next) {
User.findOne({'user._id': req.body.user._id}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    res.render('accounts/profile', { user : user});
});
```

});

You cannot send data in body of a GET request. So change it to a POST and then if you have not declared the bodyparser middleware then first declare it, then the data from your POST request will be available in your req.body.

Comment: Thanks alot for your comment, I think your answer resolved my error, 
but now I'm receiving a User model on Profile page! 
and the GET route now doesn't send the user model ! 
what should I do ?

Comment: If you have declared passport.serializeUser which I beleive is to store the user in session then just console.log(req.session) and get the user
_id from there and you can do your query.

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport#usage), to serialize and deserialize user to session use following code

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
      done(null, user.id);
    });

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Comment: I just noticed that session is not set!  I don't know why !

Comment: ohh.. `local-login` is strategy name right? Idk how to use custom names. I normally use `local` strategy.